# What Molex plug is this? 5 mm pitch, 3 way, 1 row

Tags: identification, connector, plug

I'm trying to identify this plug, it might be a different brand instead of Molex.

The pitch is 5mm between each hole on the plug, 3 way, 1 row. This plug is 3-way but only has two terminals in, so the pitch is measured between each hole.

This plug is used on Maytag MLE22 stacked commercial washer/dryer and is the female plug that plugs into a male of the same type. It has a fuse inline and is used for the main power of the machine in between the mains and a transformer.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It might help identifying it, if you can give a background what equipment had that connector, and what was it used for?

Comment: Looks more like a commonly seen connector from AMP. Is there actually a Molex logo on it, or is that a guess? I'd try looking at AMP connectors for sure.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica - There's no Molex logo on it, I just assumed it was, as I thought I'd seen one before which was Molex branded.

Answer (score 2):

looks similar to https://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/003092032_sd.pdf
Some standard  .093" Pin connector from Molex

Answer (score 0):

["Pin and socket" connectors, 5.03 mm pitch, 0.093" pin diameter](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=pin_socket_conn&&fl=0000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000-500-%7C5.03%7C3%7C%7C%7C) (My site).

Compatible with those made by TE and Molex, among others:

- MANUF. - SERIES
- [Molex](https://www.molex.com/molex/products/family/standard_093) - Standard .093 Pin and Socket 5.03 (1r) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/0pnq53c3)
- TE - [Commercial .093 Pin and Socket 5.03 (1r)](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=82181_SOFTSHELL_STANDARD_DENSITY&DocType=CS&DocLang=English&DocFilename=ENG_CS_82181_SOFTSHELL_STANDARD_DENSITY_0508.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/bfmn42qd)

https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/molex/0003097032/3071461

[image: Molex 0003097032]

{Digikey}